# How to add a command line argument to to a Run Configuration in Intelij?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, cmd, arguments

How do I add a `command line argument` to my `Spring boot` application when using `Intelij`.

My command when I open edit configurations is currently: `spring-boot:run`:

[image]

I would like to add a command line arg after this.

For reference my main class extends implements `CommandLineRunner`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in your edit configuration you select the spring boot application and there you can fill in the program arguments... see [screenshot of Application Arguments Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN8Gz.png).

[image]

This is the spring boot configuration

Comment: I ant see the spring boot configuration, only maven?

Comment: it's the same configuration

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the root of spring boot application then select 'More Run/Debug' then select last option 'modify run configuration' and this is the place where you see option on passing command line arguments.

[image]